# Is there an utility to write a pipe to a file?

Tags: php, windows, pipe, batch-processing, tee

I'm using windows in a classic cmd shell with tar & msysgit utilities available in path.

In a php script, i'm trying to get the output of this command

```
exec("tar -xzOf public/archive.ipk ./control.tar.gz | tar -xzOf - ./control", $out);
```

but exec() strips line ending and new lines, therefore, cannot be reliable for sensitives files like control.

I tried

```
exec("tar -xzOf public/archive.ipk ./control.tar.gz | tar -xzOf - ./control > temporary");
```

But temporary is CRLF line ending style !!! (when my control file is LF style)

I tried

```
exec("tar -xzOf public/archive.ipk ./control.tar.gz | tar -xzOf - ./control | php -r file_put_contents('temporary', stream_get_contents(STDIN)); ");
```

With success, but is there a simplier way ? I'm looking for a pipe-to-file utility, kind of tee, but without the stdout fork.

Comment: I guess i'll stay with tee and discard output...

Comment: `^` is the escape character in cmd.  `echo ^|>file.txt` will write a pipe to a file.  Your question isn't clear.